# How do I remove rows of a Pandas DataFrame based on a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ETF_DB = ['QQQ', 'EGFIX']
fundsret = yf.download(ETF_DB, start=datetime.date(2020,12,31), end=datetime.date(2022,4,30), interval='1mo')['Adj Close'].pct_change()
df = pd.DataFrame(fundsret)
df
```

Gives me:
[image]

I'm trying to remove the rows in the dataframe that aren't month end such as the row 2021-03-22. How do I have the dataframe go through and remove the rows where the date doesn't end in '01'?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Convert the date to datetime64
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

#select only day = 1
filtered = df.loc[df['Date'].dt.day == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean month **start**?

You can use:

```
df = df[df.index.day==1]
```

reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'],
                  index=['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01',
                         '2021-03-22', '2021-03-31'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=False)
```

output:

```
              A    B
2021-01-01  NaN  NaN
2021-02-01  NaN  NaN
2021-03-01  NaN  NaN
```

##### end of month

for the end of month, you can add 1 day and check if this jumps to the next month:

```
end = (df.index+pd.Timedelta('1d')).month != df.index.month

df = df[end]
```

or add an offset and check if the value is unchanged:

```
end = df.index == (df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0))

df = df[end]
```

output:

```
              A    B
2021-03-31  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import pandas as pd
    import re
    
    # Dummy Dictionary
    dict={
    'Date': ['2021-01-01','2022-03-01','2023-04-22','2023-04-01'],
    'Name' : ['A','B','C','D']
    }
    
    # Making a DataFrame
    df=pd.DataFrame(dict)

 # Date Pattern Required
pattern= '(\d{4})-(\d{2})-01' 

new_df=df[df['Date'].str.match(r'((\d{4})-(\d{2})-01)')]
print(new_df)
```